# Add Documentation doesn't work since Xcode 9 installed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode9

I got this problem with Xcode 9.0.1, 9.1 and 9.2. It was disabled like the following screenshot shows.
[image]

I have tried the following solutions but none of them worked.

- `sudo /usr/libexec/xpccachectl` and restart my Mac.
- `xcode-select --install` and restart.
- select code and reopen menu.

Please help me! Thanks!

**Updated**

I'm working with Objective-C.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as well. Would love to see a resolution to this.

Answer (score 1):

It works again in Xcode 9.3. I have no idea why. Maybe Apple fixed this bug.